# Git ignore not ignoring subdirectory? */labels/*?

Tags: git, gitignore

I am trying to ignore all files under a certain folder name. However, I have an issue where I repeat the folder name twice at different levels in the tree and this appears to make gitignore not honor the pattern?

Desired outcome:
What I am looking to do is ignore all file under the last labels folder.

Tried:

- The .gitignore works for other patterns so the file itself is good
- I have tried patterns:
- `*/labels/*`
- `**/labels/**`
- `**/labels/**/*`
- `labels/*`
- `labels/**`
- `labels`

Supplemental:
Directory tree like this:

```
    └── Dir
        ├── labels
        │   └── folder1
        │       └── labels
        │           ├── file1.txt
        │           ├── file2.txt
```

```
# Current Git Ignore
*/labels/*
```

Comment: While `**/labels/*` should work, it's not in your list; `labels/` should also work and is more concise; and `labels` should work but will also ignore files whose name ends with `/labels` (or consists *of* `/labels`—remember that to Git, there are no folders, there are just files with names with embedded slashes, so the top level worktree file named `labels` is effectively `/labels`). Without further details I might also guess that you're *already tracking* some files that this pattern *would* ignore if you weren't tracking those files.

Comment: Yea I checked that:
```#  new file:   refactor/Clip_1/DogDog1/labels/denim-donkey-5/labels/DogDog1_516.txt```

The file is both new and the path does have labels in it.

Comment: That file is already tracked, so you can't ignore it. You must first untrack it before it will be ignored, using `git rm --cached`. (Note that the tracked-ness of a file changes over time and is under your control at most times. Files that are in some existing commit are stuck *in* that commit *forever* as no commit can ever be changed, but you can simply stop using *that* commit.)

Comment: Pretty sure the file is not committed that line was from a git commit message that I aborted. The commit was never filed. I have also generated a unique name new directory with fresh never committed files and it has the same issue? I will give the git rm a try.

Comment: Ok gave it a try:
/data/myvideoannotationtool/refactor/Clip_1/test/DogDog2/labels/denim-donkey-5$ git rm labels/* --dry-run
fatal: pathspec 'labels/DogDog2_454.txt' did not match any files

Comment: You're using a shell that expands `*`, so you must `git rm --cached refactor/Clip_1/DogDog1/labels/denim-donkey-5/labels/DogDog1_516.txt`. Your shell replaced the one `*` with one of the names *not* in Git's index.